# Active record not saving data according to timezone in rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, ruby-on-rails-5

I set in application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific/Auckland'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local # Or :utc
```

But records still are not saving in this timezone

Comment: yes i did.......

Answer (score 0):

Records are always stored in database with UTC time. Your config timezone is just used to display time, not saving.

Comment: Could you tell us how we can go around it?

Comment: @KickButtowski I don't understand what you mean `go around it`. what is your config and expectations?

Comment: I meant how to agree database with the timezone. please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604767/activerecord-is-not-aware-of-timezones?noredirect=1#comment94072941_53604767